# Word delimiter for given locale

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocale

How do I know if a language `NSLocale` uses **spaces** for delimiting words in a sentence (like English or other roman languages) or not (like Japanese)?

I expected to find this information under [NSLocale Component Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale%5C_Class/index.html#//apple%5C_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/objectForKey:) … no. Any idea? Do I really need to set my own dictionary for this. I'd appreciate any advice or related resource.

Comment: Exactly. Welcome to Japan. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSLocal Components keys'  `NSLocaleExemplarCharacterSet` to get the set of character in that language and then see if space is part of that language character set

```
NSLocale *jpLocale = [[NSLocal alloc] initWithLocalDentifier: @"ja_JP"];

NSCharacterSet *jpCharSet = (NSCharacterSet *)[jpLocale objectForKey: NSLocaleExemplarCharacterSet]; 

[jpCharSet characterIsMember: ' '] ? NSLog("Yeah it uses space"); : NSLog("Nope");
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a great solution. As a workaround I am checking for spaces in *fullStyle* strings from a random date using the `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDate* exampleDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
NSString *testString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:exampleDate];

BOOL localeLikelyUsesSpaceAsDelimitters = [testString rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound;
```

Better ideas?